# SQLBulk Copy with trigger which fire Update query

Tags: sql, triggers, sqlbulkcopy

I have insert records from excel sheet to SQL using `SQLBulkCopy`.

Code runs fine for me.

But I have to fire Trigger based insertion.

In trigger I am inserting records in another table based on `Inserted`

that also works fine.

but if I am checking that another table already having that record which I am trying to insert and update that record than that does not works for me.

How can I solve my problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Merge statement in your Trigger if you are using SQL server 2008

Example:

```
MERGE INTO dbo.Table1 AS t
USING dbo.inserted AS i
        ON t.id= i.id
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET
      t.col1= i.col1,
      t.col2= i.col2
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
      INSERT (col1, col2)
      VALUES (i.col1, i.col2)
```

Comment: ---------------------------

---------------------------
The MERGE statement attempted to UPDATE or DELETE the same row more than once. This happens when a target row matches more than one source row. A MERGE statement cannot UPDATE/DELETE the same row of the target table multiple times. Refine the ON clause to ensure a target row matches at most one source row, or use the GROUP BY clause to group the source rows.
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------

Comment: I think you ar enot using proper key to match and update in yourtable.

Comment: actually I found that this error comes due to not having primary key in both table

Comment: for Merge statement primary key is must

Comment: I have matched proper key but those both are not primary key

Comment: then what you can do is first check those records in your table2 if exists dont inert else insert

Comment: In your trigger first check all the records from inserted table exists in table2 and get all ids which are not there in table2 and insert only those ids there